# Loaded Modules Information using a trusted lsmod command

Tags: drivers, kernel

I have copied lsmod command script from /sbin/lsmod to a directory.
I renamed lsmod to elsmod.
Now when i run this command from a script it doesn't give me any output.
what should i do to get the output.
Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`/sbin/lsmod` is NOT a "command script". It is a symbolic link to `/bin/kmod`, a binary executable. See `man ln`. `/bin/kmod` is the target of links from several files:

```
$ ls -l /sbin | grep kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr 10  2014 depmod -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr 10  2014 insmod -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr 10  2014 lsmod -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr 10  2014 modinfo -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr 10  2014 modprobe -> /bin/kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root         9 Apr 10  2014 rmmod -> /bin/kmod
```

`/bin/kmod` decides what do to based on the name it is called by, by looking at `ARGV[0]`. So, even if you copy `/bin/kmod` you will still have to call it by a name it recognizes. Type `/bin/kmod -h`

Comment: Thanks.copied kmod and renamed it ti e_kmod. Execute e_kmod list it worked fine.

Comment: What did you mean by "trusted lsmod command"? Why should you trust a local copy more than the system copy? `/bin/kmod` will be updated as needed. Will you now track necessary changes? Do you also "trust" the dynamic libraries used by `/bin/kmod`? Do `ldd /bin/kmod` and `man ldd`.

Comment: Its kinda tricky to answer this. There might be some cases where a malware writes a logical bomb in to the command executable in such a way that, if some one tries to see through strange modules that are being run in the system , it crashes the whole system wiping the data on the hard drive. This is the reason why we run trusted executable instead of system's native executable to know about the ongoings of the machine.

Comment: If "a malware" can overwrite `/bin/kmod` (`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 154616 Apr 10  2014 /bin/kmod`), you have a bigger problem than a funny modules list.  I suggest that you are putting your energy into solving the wrong problem.